# Javascript onclick only working before page fully loaded

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, laravel

So I have a function where if user click on checkbox, some input will be unhide, like below

```js
function myFunc() {
        var datInput = document.getElementById("dat");
        var everydayCheckbox = document.getElementById("everyday");

        if (everydayCheckbox.checked) {
            datInput.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            datInput.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
```

```html
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="dateranges" id="dat" style="display:none" value="$pre" />
                                    <input type="text" name="daterange" id="daterange" class="form-control date" placeholder="Choose multiple dates">
                                    <p style="color: white">
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="everyday" id="everyday" onclick="myFunc()" value="everyday" class="flat" /> Everyday
                                    </p>
                                </div>
```

The problem is, the above code only working if page not fully loaded, my first thought is that it is due to package conflict but i cant figure out which package that cause this is problem.

Here is the package i used which is located in same html with above function

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.10.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js" integrity="sha512-LsnSViqQyaXpD4mBBdRYeP6sRwJiJveh2ZIbW41EBrNmKxgr/LFZIiWT6yr+nycvhvauz8c2nYMhrP80YhG7Cw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById("daterange").disabled = true;
    };
    function myFunc() {
        var datInput = document.getElementById("dat");
        var everydayCheckbox = document.getElementById("everyday");

        if (everydayCheckbox.checked) {
            datInput.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            datInput.style.display = "none";
        }
    }

    
</script>
```

and here is the package i used from html which above function extended from, which located at bottom of html

```
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="{{asset('vendors/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js')}}"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<script src="{{asset('vendors/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js')}}"></script>
<!-- FastClick -->
<script src="{{asset('vendors/fastclick/lib/fastclick.js')}}"></script>
<!-- NProgress -->
<script src="{{asset('vendors/nprogress/nprogress.js')}}"></script>
<!-- iCheck -->
<script src="{{asset('vendors/iCheck/icheck.min.js')}}"></script>
<!-- Datatables -->
<script src="{{asset('vendors/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('vendors/datatables.net-bs/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('vendors/datatables.net-buttons/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('vendors/datatables.net-buttons-bs/js/buttons.bootstrap.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('vendors/datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.flash.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('vendors/datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.html5.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('vendors/datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.print.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('vendors/datatables.net-fixedheader/js/dataTables.fixedHeader.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('vendors/datatables.net-keytable/js/dataTables.keyTable.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('vendors/datatables.net-responsive/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('vendors/datatables.net-responsive-bs/js/responsive.bootstrap.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('vendors/datatables.net-scroller/js/dataTables.scroller.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('vendors/jszip/dist/jszip.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('vendors/pdfmake/build/pdfmake.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('vendors/pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts.js')}}"></script>
<!-- jQuery custom content scroller -->
<script src="{{asset('vendors/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js')}}"></script>
<!-- Switchery -->
<script src="{{asset('vendors/switchery/dist/switchery.min.js')}}"></script>

<!-- jQuery Smart Wizard -->
<script src="{{asset('vendors/jQuery-Smart-Wizard/js/jquery.smartWizard.js')}}"></script>

<!-- Custom Theme Scripts -->
<script src="{{asset('build/js/custom.js')}}"></script>
```

Comment: Please read [mcve]. The advice there ("Divide and conquer" in particular) should guide you to locating the conflict yourself.